# How do I display data from Room database rather than hash code? (Android Studio, Java)

Tags: java, sql, android-studio, android-room

I have successfully stored testdata in `Room` using `@insert` and now would like to display the data using the `interface`

```
@Query( "SELECT * FROM users" )
List<UserEntity>getAllUsers();
```

If I use the following:

```
Log.d("TAG ", "" + myDatabase.getUserDao().getAllUsers());
```

I get hash data like this:

```
com.slothmode.roomjavaexercise.UserEntity@8024b17
```

If I use the same `@Query` in a SQL-browser, I get the proper data, so I know that it should work if I only knew how to show it in the proper way. Any ideas?

Comment: Implement `toString()`.

Comment: How would you get hashcode in SQL-browser?

Comment: @GreenhouseVeg It only gave me a bunch of hash data.

Comment: @Antoniossss I didn't. I got the proper data in the SQL-browser. The hash data was in Android Studio.

Comment: @tore, yes, that is default implementation. Override it in your `UserEntity` class to print anything else.

Comment: @GreenhouseVeg Hm, ok, how do I override it? Could you elaborate or give an example? :)

Comment: You can use Android Studio to generate a toString method and modify it from there. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html#generate-tostring

Comment: @tore, now you know what to do, but you should do it yourself, it is not hard. Direct your questions to Google instead and take it from there ;)

Comment: Alright, many thanks! :)